# Documents confirming the legality of the software

Tags: license

In my country Economic Crimes Bureau<sup>1</sup>  checks organizations for legality of installed computer software, sometimes. I'm still not a busyness owner (but I may became one) and it is [scary](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=epidemic%20police%20criminality) for me to.

As far as I know Apple software is protected by DMCA and recent versions don't even have a box version. DMCA is US law and it means nothing to local police, to confirm the legality of the software the license agreement or license to use the software is required. Such agreements must be on paper otherwise they are [have no legal power](http://translate.google.com.ua/translate?sl=uk&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://pravotoday.in.ua/ua/press-centre/publications/pub-48&act=url).

So question is **how to get written (on paper) license agreement or license** to use the software (Apple OSX)?

---

<sup>1</sup> It's called 'УБЕЗ' in Ukraine and 'ОБЭП' in Russia.

I've already asked related questions on [Russian Google Answers](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=03d4f59e83974de0), but I couldn't come up with a better place for this question than this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operating system is covered by the Apple End User License Agreement (EULA) and you can find it in PDF form on [this page](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/). My suggestion is to print the EULA and then to attach the receipt for the hardware (that the software came with) or the receipt for the software purchase to it. Then you have some documentation.

Comment: Thank's for trying to help but I'm not sure that EULA only will help (even notarized translation).

Comment: I'm not sure what other documents there could be apart from EULA and receipt of purchase? Your EULA *is* your license to use the software.